# How much bigger is sex drive in men than in women?

Tags: sexuality, gender, sex-differences

There are several studies that determine that sex drive in men is bigger than in women (which, anyway, is something that almost anyone can conclude by observing).

Here are some web pages examining these studies:

https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/dating-and-mating/202003/how-high-sex-drive-works-differently-in-men-and-women

https://www.aarp.org/home-family/sex-intimacy/info-2014/sexual-desire-and-gender-castleman.html

https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.1207/S15327957PSPR0503_5?journalCode=psra

That's not to say that women do not have sex drive or a very little one, but the fact is that it's bigger in men.

Anyway, despite these studies existing, there seems to be none that gets into  quantifying how much bigger it is, to measure how each characteristic that influences sex drive weights to obtain an average value for men and then one for women and check how much bigger it's for men compared to women.

Is there such a precise study that quantifies how much bigger it is or, at least, some approximation to that value done with some estimations even if not done in a very rigurous way?

Comment: All of the links you post include quantification or link to studies that include quantification. What about those is not suitable?

Comment: @BryanKrause, what I search is for a number that summarizes all that has to do with sex drive, i. e "Men have 3 times as much sex drive as women", in which each of the aspects that have to do have been weigthed properly (should, for example, fantasizing about sex have the same weight as the measured arousal from watching sexual images?) Links show it's bigger in men, but there's no measurement as the one I'm indicating.

Comment: I don't think that sort of number makes any sense. 3 times more *what*? What are the units of "sex drive"? This isn't physics where we're talking about a literal force.